# Apple Mach-O Linker Error XCODE 5

Tags: xcode5, linker-errors

http://pingnator.com/help/OS%20X%20Mavericks-2014-06-24-09-00-21.png

---

```
    Ld /Users/STIGPING/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlappyPing-fkdkochwxretapaxarroygfgvhrp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlappyPing.app/FlappyPing normal i386
    cd "/Users/STIGPING/Desktop/Apps/Flappy Bird"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/STIGPING/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlappyPing-fkdkochwxretapaxarroygfgvhrp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/STIGPING/Downloads/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.9-2.3/New -LFolder -LWith -LItems -F/Users/STIGPING/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlappyPing-fkdkochwxretapaxarroygfgvhrp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/STIGPING/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlappyPing-fkdkochwxretapaxarroygfgvhrp/Build/Intermediates/FlappyPing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlappyPing.build/Objects-normal/i386/FlappyPing.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework Accelerate -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -framework CoreTelephony -framework StoreKit -framework GameKit -framework AVFoundation -lGoogleAdMobAds -framework AudioToolbox -framework AdSupport -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework SpriteKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/STIGPING/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlappyPing-fkdkochwxretapaxarroygfgvhrp/Build/Intermediates/FlappyPing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlappyPing.build/Objects-normal/i386/FlappyPing_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/STIGPING/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlappyPing-fkdkochwxretapaxarroygfgvhrp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlappyPing.app/FlappyPing

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/STIGPING/Downloads/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.9-2.3/New'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LFolder'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LWith'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LItems'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

I have been searching but haven't found the solution yet. If Anyone can help me it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Please add the text to your question as it can 1) be read by everyone 2) be copied and pasted (for searching and quoting in an answer) 3) be read on this page.

Comment: Is this all I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Xcode project settings contains a *Linker Search Path* section where those directories have been added (or possibly they have been added to the *Additional Linker Flags* section).

If they are wrong then remove them.

Comment: Thanks!
This answer helped me alot :) I went into "Build Settings" and "Search Paths" and the folder it pointed at was empty. I had to redownload ADMob for iOS and drag the files back into "Supporting Files". I also cleaned up the "Library Search Paths" because it had more than needed.