# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (linker command failed, library not found for -liPhone-lib)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, linker-errors

I get this error when trying to build my game (using Unity 4.5) in Xcode 5.0. I have tried to remove paths under "Library/Framework Search Paths" (seems to be the solution for many) but with no success.

I'm using the "Google Play Game Services" plugin and "Social Mobile Plugin" (which uses Facebook SDK for Unity).

Since I don't have much experience of Xcode I don't really know what I'm dealing with here, so I'm sorry for the long error message below but maybe someone can get something out of it:

(I have also tried to find this "liPhone library" but I guess I misunderstand something because I can't find anything like that anywhere.)

---

Apple Mach-O Linker Error:

```
ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

The rest that comes with the error:

```
Ld /Users/lw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-erqtfljbogqrgkbcdfzjhxkvjikg/Build/Products/MyGame.app/MyGame normal armv7
    cd /Users/lw/Documents/MyGame/MyGame_xcode
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/lw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-erqtfljbogqrgkbcdfzjhxkvjikg/Build/Products -L/Users/lw/Documents/MyGame/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FacebookSDK -F/Users/lw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-erqtfljbogqrgkbcdfzjhxkvjikg/Build/Products -F/Users/lw/Documents/GPG/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.0 -F/Users/lw/Documents/GPG/GooglePlayGames-iOS-SDK -F/Users/lw/Documents/MyGame/MyGame_xcode/Libraries -filelist /Users/lw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-erqtfljbogqrgkbcdfzjhxkvjikg/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -ObjC -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -lz -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework GooglePlus -framework GooglePlayGames -lc++ -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreData -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -liconv.2 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -weak_framework iAd -liPhone-lib -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework GameKit -weak-lsqlite3.0 /Users/lw/Documents/MyGame/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.a -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Social -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/lw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-erqtfljbogqrgkbcdfzjhxkvjikg/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/lw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-erqtfljbogqrgkbcdfzjhxkvjikg/Build/Products/MyGame.app/MyGame
```

Comment: Check your valid architectures from your project's build settings. Remove armv64 from there and clean and build your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Mach-O Linker Error XCODE 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380391/apple-mach-o-linker-error-xcode-5)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032987/how-to-solve-mach-o-linker-error-in-ios7-xcode-5-0-1

Comment: Manthan: Thank you but already tried that without success I'm afraid.

Comment: Neeku: Thanks but I've been looking for these "backslash" issues concerning the search paths, but I don't have any.

Comment: Managed to solve it. It was another "hidden" error that caused this, an error that "hid" behind the Apple Mach-O Linker Error after I removed some search paths. The real error was caused by a missing framework, which in my case was "CoreTelephony.framework".

(I can't add this as a solution/answer yet since I just registered, so I added it here as a comment.)